# what is the estimated variance of predictions from mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I have fitted the following lmer model (assume it is "correct") with lme4:

```
Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (1 | year) + (1 | site) + (1 | site:year)
```

where X1-X3 are continuous covariates. Y and X's were measured for same n=30 subjects in each of the same s=10 sites in each of the same y=10 years.

Estimates of the variances are (with obvious notation) Vy, Vs, Vsy, Verror.

Yhat for a  new site in a new year was obtained with predict() and its variance (or SE^2) was obtained by specifying reform = ~0.

QUESTION:
How should I calculate a confidence (more properly, prediction) interval for the mean of all subjects (population) in the new year new site where I measured the X's in 30 individuals?

My guess is that Variance of Yhat is;

```
Vyhat <- SE^2 + Vy + Vs + Vsy
```

And CI would be:

```
c( Yhat - 2 * sqrt(Vyhat), Yhat + 2 * sqrt(Vyhat) )
```

Thank you.